# Homogeneous Inequality problem unsolved

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

> Let ${x,y,z}$ be positive real numbers.
>
> Prove that
>
> $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{yz+\frac{x^4}{y^2}+\frac{x^4}{z^2}} \leq 1$

Here’s my try:

By A.M.-G.M. we know that

$\frac{yz}{2}+\frac{yz}{2}+\frac{x^4}{y^2}+\frac{x^4}{z^2}\geq$ $4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{4}}x^2.$

So we get $L.H.S \leq \frac{3}{4\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{4}}}.$

But this inequality is never hold

How can I prove that it is less than $1$?